# how to get binded drop down list while users pagging and sorting in asp.net 3.5

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have grid view which have two drop down list. so user can change drop down list value at run time. here is my grid view design code :

```
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="status_id">
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="status_id">
<HeaderTemplate>
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbut_sortstatus1" runat="server" 
CommandArgument="status_id" CommandName="Sort" CssClass="normaltext" 
Font-Bold="true" Text="Status"></asp:LinkButton>
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="placeholderstatus1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DDL_StatusList1" runat="server" 
DataTextField="status_name" DataValueField="Id" AppendDataBoundItems="true" 
AutoPostBack="True" 
onselectedindexchanged="DDL_StatusList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>
</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID ="DDL_StatusList1" 
EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />  
</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</ItemTemplate>
<HeaderStyle CssClass="headinglist_bg" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
<ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```

how ever this is my Page_Load code :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            Panel_View.Visible = false;
            Session["SearchtText"] = null;
            Session["ColumnName"] = null;
            this.FillGrid((String)Session["ColumnName"] ?? null, (String)Session["SearchtText"] ?? null);
            Bind_DDL_Column_List();
            Bind_DDL_Title();
            Bind_DDL_Status();
            Bind_DDL_Group();
            Bind_DDL_Countries();
        }
        this.GetData();
    }
```

and here is my one of drop down list bind method that shows how i binding grid view drop down list.

```
     public void Bind_DDL_Group()
        {
            using (DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext())
            {
                var query = db.Groups.Select(g=>g).OrderBy(g=>g.Group_name).ToList();
                DataSet myDataset = new DataSet();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
                dt.Columns.Add("Group_name", typeof(string));
                foreach (var item in query)
                {
                    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                    dr["Id"] = item.Id.ToString();
                    dr["Group_name"] = item.Group_name.ToString();
                    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                }
                myDataset.Tables.Add(dt);
                DDL_GroupList.DataSource = myDataset;
                DDL_GroupList.DataBind();
                DropDownList bind_dropdownlist;
                foreach (GridViewRow grdRow in GV_ViewUserList.Rows)
                {
                    bind_dropdownlist = (DropDownList)(GV_ViewUserList.Rows[grdRow.RowIndex].Cells[8].FindControl("DDL_GroupList1"));
                    bind_dropdownlist.DataSource = myDataset;
                    bind_dropdownlist.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

however at Page load first time it's works successfully but when user clicks sorting or pagging then drop down list get empty. how ever i binds them in `(!Page.IsPostBack)` of `Page_Load`.

what I'm doing wrong here..
please help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please put dropdown binding code out of if(!Page.IsPostBack) condition

Because when go to another page in gridview Page will be posted back to server

and if(!Page.IsPostBack) condition will return false.

Change your code to

```
if   (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        Panel_View.Visible = false;
        Session["SearchtText"] = null;
        Session["ColumnName"] = null;
        this.FillGrid((String)Session["ColumnName"] ?? null, (String)Session["SearchtText"] ?? null);
        Bind_DDL_Column_List();
        Bind_DDL_Title();
        Bind_DDL_Countries();
    }
        Bind_DDL_Status();
        Bind_DDL_Group();
    this.GetData();
```

Comment: ya i do but still same problem.

Comment: here i only need two methods for grid view drop down list binding. so update ur code.

Comment: please send me full code if possible so i can check

Comment: for which specific event do u want to see.